# Как определить сколько страниц (листов А4) займёт XML файл при печати на принтере?

Tags: c#, xml, печать

У меня есть код, который распечатывает содержимое XML файла на листе. Мне нужно, перед тем как распечатать файл узнать, сколько листов затратит принтер. Может кто-то подскажет как я могу это сделать? В интернете я нашёл несколько вариантов:

```
public int GetNumberOfPrintedPages(string filePath)
{
PrintDocument document = new PrintDocument();
document.DocumentName = filePath;
document.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = filePath;

PrintController printController = new StandardPrintController();
document.PrintController = printController;

int pageCount = 0;
document.PrintPage += (sender, e) =>
{
    pageCount++;
    // Выполните здесь любую дополнительную обработку страницы перед печатью
};

document.Print();

return pageCount; 
}
```

Но этот вариант не подходит, так как он показывает количество затрачиваемых страниц уже после печати, а мне нужно до. Так же есть такой вариант:

```
double pageSizeWidth = 210;
double pageSizeHeight = 297;
int xmlLength = formattedXml.Length;
int charsPerPage = (int)((pageSizeWidth * pageSizeHeight) / 5);
int totalPages = xmlLength / charsPerPage + 1;
```

Здесь просто берутся размеры стандартного А4, берётся количество символов в XML файле и высчитывается примерное количество страниц. Этот вариант тоже не подходит, так как вычисление количества затрачиваемых страниц не точное (большая погрешность).
Я, так же обращался с этим вопросом в чат GPT и он мне скинул такой код:

```
using System.Drawing.Printing;

public int GetNumberOfPrintedPages(string filePath)
{
PrintDocument document = new PrintDocument();
document.DocumentName = filePath;
document.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = filePath;
PrintController printController = new StandardPrintController();
document.PrintController = printController;

int pageCount = 0;
document.PrintController = new PreviewPrintController();
var printPreviewPageInfo = document.PrintController.GetPreviewPageInfo();

while (printPreviewPageInfo != null)
{
pageCount++;
// Выполните здесь любую дополнительную обработку страницы перед печатью

printPreviewPageInfo = 
document.PrintController.GetPreviewPageInfo(printPreviewPageInfo.PageNumber + 1);
}

return pageCount;
}
```

Однако тут я столкнулся с проблемой. У меня у объекта PrintController просто нет метода GetPreviewPageInfo(). Возможно этот код использует другую версию System.Drawing.Printing.
Есть ли способ получить точное количество  страниц перед печатью XML файла?

Comment: На мой взгляд, с таким подходом это всегда будет гаданием на кофейной гуще, т.к. необходимо учесть очень много параметров и нюансов. Не рассматривали вариант с "печатью" в PDF с последующим определением количества страниц?

Comment: Такой вариант рассматривал, но конвертировать XML в Pdf возможно, как я понял, только через дополнительно установленные библиотеки, а у меня к сожалению нет такой возможности. Единственная библиотека в моём вооружении, которая может работать с  Pdf это ITextSharp, но она похоже не имеет возможности конвертации.

Comment: Вроде как [умеет](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71234592)...

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас гляну